# How to change icon color according to rating value? Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to change the icon color according to the movie rating.
I made a function that receives the value of the classification and returns a value for the className inside the svg. However, all icons turn red. Someone help me to solve this problem.

**Conditions for changing color.**

**Rating: 0 to 100**

0 - white

20 or 40 - red

60 - orange

80 or 100 - green

```
//Punctuation/Note
const setVote = (note) => {
    console.log("NOTE", note);
    if (note === 0) { // 0
        return "white";
    } else if (note >= 20 || note <= 40) { 
        return "red";
    } else if (note === 60) { 
        return "orange";
    } else return "green"; 
};
```

```
<div className='box-note'>
                        <span className='rating'>{rating}</span>
                        <i className='icon-vote-like'>
                            <svg id="Icon_Thumbs_Up_Filled" data-name="Icon / Thumbs Up / Filled" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="17" height="17" viewBox="0 0 17 17">
                                <rect id="Box" width="17" height="17" fill="none" />
                                <path id="Path_1994" fill="#6cbe61" className={setVote(rating)} data-name="Path 1994" d="M97-8.286h2.805v-8.229H97Zm15.429-7.543a1.391,1.391,0,0,0-1.4-1.371H106.6l.666-3.134.021-.219a1.021,1.021,0,0,0-.309-.727l-.743-.72-4.615,4.519a1.326,1.326,0,0,0-.414.967v6.857a1.391,1.391,0,0,0,1.4,1.371h6.312a1.394,1.394,0,0,0,1.29-.837l2.118-4.834a1.328,1.328,0,0,0,.1-.5v-1.31l-.007-.007Z" transform="translate(-96.143 23.714)" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.white {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

.orange {
  fill: #ffa500;
}

.green {
  fill: #008000;
}

.red {
  fill: #ff0000;
}
```

**Current state**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong condition here:

```
else if (note >= 20 || note <= 40) { 
        return "red";
```

instead of `||` should be `&&`.

But if you want to implement ranges, you should also correct other conditions:

```
const setVote = (note) => {
    console.log("NOTE", note);
    if (note <20) { // 0-19
        return "white";
    } else if (note >= 20 && note <= 40) { // 20-40 
        return "red";
    } else if (note > 40 && note <= 60) { // 41-60
        return "orange";
    } else return "green"; // 60+
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const setVote = (note) => {
    console.log("NOTE", note);
    if (note === 0) { // 0
        return "white";
    } else if (note >= 20 && note <= 40) { 
        return "red";
    } else if (note === 60) { 
        return "orange";
    } else return "green"; 
};
```

Better with interval:

```
const setVote = (note) => {
    console.log("NOTE", note);
    if (note < 20) { // 0
        return "white";
    } else if (note >= 20 && note <= 40) { 
        return "red";
    } else if (note >= 40 && note <= 60) { 
        return "orange";
    } else return "green"; 
};
```

The idea is to use AND instead of OR

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it should be **===**. Look:

```
 const setVote = (note) => {
         console.log("NOTE", note);
         if (note === 0) { 
             return "white";
         } else if (note === 20 || note === 40) { 
             return "red";
         } else if (note === 60) {
             return "orange";
         } else return "green";
     };
```